# Restrict membership types by contact type

Tags: civimember, contact-types

Is there any easy way to restrict the membership types available to be added to certain contact types from the new membership screen within CiviCRM?

We have an organisational membership class that is inherited by employees and volunteers. I want to stop staff accidentally assigning that membership type to individuals or ineligible organisation types.

Comment: If this is for backend admin users, eg 'Add Membership' on a contact page, then it would need a custom extension I expect. If you can persuade them to use a different approach, then the suggestion by yurg might work, or you could explore if FormBuilder can deliver this (not clear if you are taking payments as part of the workflow or not)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps add a set of Custom Fields used for Memberships and use it in a Profile with the "Limit listings to a specific Group?" option turned on?